# A little problem with a simple program for coin toss in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm new to javascript programming and it is not clear to me how execution flow is handled. I used an animation from "Animation.css" in order to create a program for the toss of a coin. The problem is that when I go to make javascript add the class for the animation, it doesn't run and the console.log prints me that no class has been added. Can you help me and make me understand why? Many thanks in advance! ^^

My code is here:

```js
//variabili globali
//let clickNumber=0;

//HTML to JS
coinContainer = document.querySelector('.coin-container');
coin = document.querySelector('#coin');

//Events
coin.addEventListener('click',flipCoin);

//Funzioni
function flipCoin(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    let head = "https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-57e97e36918b359f28e86b8cbf567436.webp";
    let tail = "https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-9c81a54813716fccd8e3608ab2f51dcf";
    scelta=Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if(scelta===0){
        event.target.setAttribute('class','animated flip');
        event.target.setAttribute('src',head);
        console.log(event.target);
        //wait a lil bit
        for(let i=0;i>1000000000;i++){
            //
        }
        event.target.setAttribute('class','');
        console.log(event.target);
    }
    else{
        event.target.setAttribute('class','animated flip');
        event.target.setAttribute('src',tail);
        console.log(event.target);
        //wait a lil bit
        for(let i=0;i>1000000000;i++){
        //
        }
        event.target.setAttribute('class','');
        console.log(event.target);
    }
    //clickNumber++;
}
```

```css
/* ANIMATE.CSS */
.animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
  
  .animated.infinite {
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  
  .animated.delay-1s {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
  
  .animated.delay-2s {
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  
  .animated.delay-3s {
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }
  
  .animated.delay-4s {
    animation-delay: 4s;
  }
  
  .animated.delay-5s {
    animation-delay: 5s;
  }
  
  .animated.fast {
    animation-duration: 800ms;
  }
  
  .animated.faster {
    animation-duration: 500ms;
  }
  
  .animated.slow {
    animation-duration: 2s;
  }
  
  .animated.slower {
    animation-duration: 3s;
  }
  
  @media (print), (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .animated {
      animation-duration: 1ms !important;
      transition-duration: 1ms !important;
      animation-iteration-count: 1 !important; 
    }
  }

  /* END ANIMATE CSS */

  /* FLIP.CSS */
  @keyframes flip {
    from {
      transform: perspective(400px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -360deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
  
    40% {
      transform: perspective(400px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 150px)
        rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -190deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
  
    50% {
      transform: perspective(400px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 150px)
        rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -170deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
  
    80% {
      transform: perspective(400px) scale3d(0.95, 0.95, 0.95) translate3d(0, 0, 0)
        rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
  
    to {
      transform: perspective(400px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
  }
  
  .animated.flip {
    backface-visibility: visible;
    animation-name: flip;
  }
  /* END FLIP CSS */

  /* MY STYLE */

  body{
      background: #555555;
  }

  #coin{
      width: 21.5rem;
      height: 21.5rem;
  }

  .coin-container{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top:15vh;
  }

  /* END MY STYLE */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="moneta.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="coin-container">
        <img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-57e97e36918b359f28e86b8cbf567436.webp" id="coin">
    </div>
   
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class before adding it to trigger the animation.
To force the animation to reset, I have added element.offsetWidth to force a reflow.

```js
//variabili globali
//let clickNumber=0;

//HTML to JS
coinContainer = document.querySelector('.coin-container');
coin = document.querySelector('#coin');

//Events
coin.addEventListener('click',flipCoin);

//Funzioni
function flipCoin(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    let head = "https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-57e97e36918b359f28e86b8cbf567436.webp";
    let tail = "https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-9c81a54813716fccd8e3608ab2f51dcf";
    scelta=Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if(scelta===0){
        event.target.setAttribute('src',head);
        
        event.target.className='';
        event.target.offsetWidth;
        event.target.className='animated flip';
    }
    else{
        event.target.setAttribute('src',tail);
        event.target.className='';
        event.target.offsetWidth;
        event.target.className='animated flip';
    }
    //clickNumber++;
}
```

```css
.animatereset {
  animation-iteration-count: 0;
}

.animated { animation-iteration-count: 1 }
/* ANIMATE.CSS */
.animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
  
  .animated.infinite {
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  
  .animated.delay-1s {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
  
  .animated.delay-2s {
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  
  .animated.delay-3s {
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }
  
  .animated.delay-4s {
    animation-delay: 4s;
  }
  
  .animated.delay-5s {
    animation-delay: 5s;
  }
  
  .animated.fast {
    animation-duration: 800ms;
  }
  
  .animated.faster {
    animation-duration: 500ms;
  }
  
  .animated.slow {
    animation-duration: 2s;
  }
  
  .animated.slower {
    animation-duration: 3s;
  }
  
  @media (print), (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .animated {
      animation-duration: 1ms !important;
      transition-duration: 1ms !important;
      animation-iteration-count: 1 !important; 
    }
  }

  /* END ANIMATE CSS */

  /* FLIP.CSS */
  @keyframes flip {
    from {
      transform: perspective(400px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -360deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
  
    40% {
      transform: perspective(400px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 150px)
        rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -190deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
  
    50% {
      transform: perspective(400px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 150px)
        rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -170deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
  
    80% {
      transform: perspective(400px) scale3d(0.95, 0.95, 0.95) translate3d(0, 0, 0)
        rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
  
    to {
      transform: perspective(400px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
  }
  
  .animated.flip {
    backface-visibility: visible;
    animation-name: flip;
  }
  /* END FLIP CSS */

  /* MY STYLE */

  body{
      background: #555555;
  }

  #coin{
      width: 21.5rem;
      height: 21.5rem;
  }

  .coin-container{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      margin-top:15vh;
  }

  /* END MY STYLE */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="moneta.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="coin-container">
        <img src="https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-57e97e36918b359f28e86b8cbf567436.webp" id="coin">
    </div>
   
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is a problem. When I click the coin for the first time the animation is performed, but for each subsequent click it switches from one image to another without carrying out the animation

Comment: for the moment I've solved by adding " animationIterationCount " incremented by 1 for each click to the style of the animation and it works well

Comment: I've added a fix to trigger reflow so the animation can reset.  Other methods here:  https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/    Probably the best is animation-play-state

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow. wanted to just point out a few **VERY** important things to keep in mind when using stackoverflow to ask a question. it is imperative that you produce a [**Minimal and Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem and provide the actual error on your post. for reference, pls refer to the community guideline on how to post a [**good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

i did get a chance to run your code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1jqurh0/5/), the javascript portion of your code seems to be working fine. the problem seems to be coming from the css

```
  @media (print), (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
    .animated {
      animation-duration: 1ms !important;
      transition-duration: 1ms !important;
      animation-iteration-count: 1 !important; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice that I will exploit in the future ^^. Indeed I've solved the problem by increasing that "animation-iteration-count: 1" for each click made and it works well.

Comment: Noting that he did have a minimum reproducible example, and the css was taken from the original animate.css code.  The original code depends on you hooking animationend and removing the animation before continuing the next one.  Increasing the iteration count by 1 each time fixes it by telling it to iterate one more time.